# Cannot vertically align button inside UL

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to vertically align the icon to match the level of the other items on the list. But whenever I try to pad the icon from the top, the entire row moves down.

I've tried to add all sorts of things, but it doesn't work.

[image]

The code looks like:

```
<ul style={{ listStyle: `none`, float: `right`}}>
  <button>
    <img src={moon} alt="Dark mode" width="20rem"  height="20rem"/>
  </button>
  <ListLink to="/projects">projects</ListLink>
  <ListLink to="/blog">blog</ListLink>
  <ListLink to="/projects">books</ListLink>
  <ListLink to="/contact">ideas </ListLink>
</ul>
```

The CSS is:

```
img {
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

button {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `flexbox`.

```
ul {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

You could also add `justify-content: space-evenly;` to then space items evenly.

You can also have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in order to learn more about `flexboxes`.

Comment: It will work with anything really if used properly. Have a look at the link that I have provided. It is just about wrapping elements that you need to adjust and then using appropriate commands. Made similar sample to yours here: https://jsfiddle.net/8orpst47/ You can see how everything is vertically aligned. `Flexboxes` will also make your life much easier when it comes to responsiveness btw.

Comment: it still doesn't align in my code for some reason https://ibb.co/k29v4wT

Comment: It could be because of some other styling that you have in your app. You can clearly see on the example that I have provided, given your code that it works perfectly.

Comment: is there any way I could just move the img a little upwards using any other trick? I have been at this problem for 3 hours now.

Comment: It is better to avoid hard-coding `CSS` rules if `flexbox` can do the job for you with much less code. Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/qz8xs9kp/2/ Remove all unnecessary styling from the button as well.

Comment: for reference, this is my button styling: https://ibb.co/wLBJsvy

Comment: As mentioned, please remove all unnecessary `margins` and `paddings` from the `button` and let `flexbox` handle it. In your case, it could really just be an `img`, without the `button` wrapper but I am not aware of the entire overview of the app so I will leave that there.